# CoinmarketCap API, 24h volume is greater then 7d volume, how is that possible?

Tags: api, math, cryptocurrency, coinmarketcap

I am trying to understand the data I get from [CoinmarketCap API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/) but I have a hard time figuring out how it is possible for the 24 hour volume to surpass the 7 days volume?

Example: Tesla tokenized stock Bittrex (TSLA), with ID: 7919

URL = https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest?id=7919&convert=USD&aux=volume_7d

As of right now the return data is:

```
"data": {
        "7919": {
            "id": 7919,
            "name": "Tesla tokenized stock Bittrex",
            "symbol": "TSLA",
            "slug": "tesla-tokenized-stock-bittrex",
            "last_updated": "2021-11-01T18:49:07.000Z",
            "quote": {
                "USD": {
                    "price": 1162.0225130926194,
                    "volume_24h": 24207.58836555,
                    "volume_7d": 16413.00204064,
                    "volume_change_24h": 6693.5029,
                    "percent_change_1h": -0.28201653,
                    "percent_change_24h": 4.429778,
                    "percent_change_7d": 15.46871256,
                    "percent_change_30d": 49.19294983,
                    "percent_change_60d": 59.53607702,
                    "percent_change_90d": 62.49791811,
                    "market_cap": 0,
                    "market_cap_dominance": 0,
                    "fully_diluted_market_cap": 0,
                    "last_updated": "2021-11-01T18:49:07.000Z"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the volume for the past 24 hours is bigger then the volume for the past 7 days. How is that possible?

This example is not the only one. As of right now, I have found the following id's where the 24h volume surpass 7d volume: `6760, 3149, 4112, 6482, 5623, and 7919`

Comment: What units are used? Is the "volume" really a flow rate perhaps?

Comment: It is in USD. The documentation says it is: "Rolling 24 hour / 7 days adjusted volume in the specified currency (USD)". I don't know much about flow rate, how is that different?

Comment: Flow rate would be $/time

Comment: What does "adjuted volume" mean? What is the adjustment?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the values coming from a specifc API. OP does not appear to have any programming problems.

Comment: Also, try to find some docs about the exact time spans involved. It's likely that 7 days does not include 24 hours based on what you show.

Comment: I understand, please point me to the right place then. I'm not sure what "adjusted" means, but they also have a reported volume where I get same values and doc says: "Rolling 24 hour / 7 days reported volume in the specified currency (USD)"

Comment: SO is not really for that. If the API docs are not sufficient, file a bug report or ask the provider by other means. Your snippet is a good example of why the docs need to improve.